# How to align dropdown block to the right edge of Select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I have next situation
http://take.ms/1KIFG

And I want this
http://take.ms/2NW6z

Comment: Can you please share some code of the described situation?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using CSS. I gave class

```
.select2-container--open {
  right: 0 !important;
  left: auto !important;
}
```